# Automatically Import WordPress Blog to Facebook Page

Tags: posts, rss, facebook

I managed to import wordpress post to Facebook with this:

http://www.insidefacebook.com/2009/02/22/how-to-import-your-blog-into-facebook/

When i create new post, Facebook doesn't **show any new posts** after the importation.

Anyone have a idea how to keep showing the post created in Wordpress to Facebook after the importation ?

Note: Sorry, not pretty good in English :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but you can use publicize through wordpress to automatically use your blog posts as facebook status updates.

Go into your Dashboard, select My Blogs, go to the Publicity column, check Facebook.

Comment: To be clear, Publicize is currently only available on WordPress.com, not self-hosted installs.

Comment: Publicize has since become available to self-hosted WordPress installs through the [Jetpack](http://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

We use this plugin - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/ to post to our facebook page at http://www.facebook.com/TheCheckeredFlag

You can set it up so it'll automatically post to a page or profile on facebook.

Not sure if this is what you are looking as it seems you might want to import a whole blog, but hopefully this will be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plug-in social media-plug-in

Publish posts automatically to social media networks like Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/social-media-auto-publish/

Answer (score -1):

For automatic posting to your facebook page, hopefully first you're using a page as opposed to a personal profile.  Pages are publicly viewable.

You'll probably also need to create an app for facebook as well.

This plugin works for pages.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook-auto-publish/screenshots/